# Correctly use getVar() in Cobbler provisioning server

Tags: cobbler

In the Cobbler kickstart file, I want to use `getVar()` for templating purpose. Specifically, I want the `$root_password_crypted` variable be set to `$password_crypted` variable if present in `ksmeta`, or `$default_password_crypted` otherwise. If I drop the following at the beginning of the preseed file, it doesn't seem to work.

> set $root_password_crypted = $getVar('$password_crypted',
>   '$default_password_crypted')

What will the correct syntax be?